# Flask - calling functions passed into a class

Tags: python, flask

I have a situation where I need to have Flask call a function in another class. For example, my "WebServer" class takes an argument that is the handler for another function. The constructor for this class stores this function argument into a variable called foo, which ideally, Flask could call later. For example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
foo = None

class WebServer:
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        foo()

    def __init__(self,myFunc):
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False)
        foo = myFunc
```

Now obviously that's not going to work because of Flask's application context. In this case, foo is always "None". What is the best way to do something like this? I tried looking into Flask's global variables, but it didn't seem like it was going to work for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make `foo` global in the `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self,myFunc):
    global foo
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False)
    foo = myFunc
```

It's not nice, but it should work. Alternatively, just pass it using [app configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/).

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. Flask, as I understand it, doesn't work with globals in this way. When I tried to implement this, it still always shows up as "None"

Comment: Nevermind, it seems global variables do work, I was just using them wrong! Not a perfect solution, but hey, it works. Thanks!